# Console logs of Cordova app not appearing in logcat once it is signed

Tags: cordova

While developing I am able to remotely debug an APK generated by Apache Cordova using `console.log`'s and watching their output in `chrome://inspect/#devices`.

Once signed however, I seem to be unable to see any of those `console.log`'s in the logcat file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that feature was removed on cordova-android 9

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/950